# Overriding conversion of primitive data types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In the code below I am trying to overload the `=` operator of `int`. So that I could support `int A= &d` statements in my program.

```
class Data{
public:
    int a;
    Data(int A): a(A) {}
    operator int()  {return a;}
};

int operator=(int &lhs, Data* rhs){
    lhs = rhs->a;
    return lhs;
}

int main(){
    Data d(10);
    int A = &d;
    return 0;
}
```

But it's giving compile time error:

> error: ‘int operator=(int&, Data*)’ must be a
>   nonstatic member function  int operator=(int &lhs, Data* rhs){
>   test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   test1.cpp: error: invalid
>   conversion from ‘Data*’ to
>   ‘int’ [-fpermissive]   int A = &d;

Please suggest me the right way of overloading the operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overload an assignment to `int`. As the compiler tells you, `operator=` has to be a non-static member function of a class, end of story.

You already have the conversion to `int` in your class, so you can write `int A = d;`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need assignment operator (`operator=`) overload in your class. Moreover, it cannot take two arguments.

All you need is cast operator (your `operator int()  {return a;}`) and a proper assignment like `int A = d;`. When you write `&` before `d`, you put address of `d` into `A` if `int` is wide enough to store pointers on your system.